# How to avoid axis labels to overlap in ggplot2 while at the same forcing one of the possible labels to be always displayed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `scale_y_discrete(guide_axis(check.overlap = T)))` in order to avoid axis labels to overlap. However, I wish a specific label to be always displayed. Below is a small example were the desired label is underlined and in bold. When I raise `N`, it is not visible anymore. How can I specify that I want this specific label to be always displayed? (If the solution could avoid reordering the labels, it would be really cool!).

```r
library(ggplot2)

N              = 20
df             = data.frame(parameters = paste("paramters", seq(N), sep = "_"))
df$parameters  = factor(df$parameters, levels = df$parameters, ordered = T)

best           = 9
breaks         = levels(df$parameters)
labels         = as.expression(breaks)
labels[[best]] = bquote(underline(bold(.(labels[[best]]))))


p = ggplot(df, aes(y = parameters)) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = breaks,
                   labels = labels,
                   guide  = guide_axis(check.overlap = T))

N              = 75
df             = data.frame(parameters = paste("paramters", seq(N), sep = "_"))
df$parameters  = factor(df$parameters, levels = df$parameters, ordered = T)

best           = 9
breaks         = levels(df$parameters)
labels         = as.expression(breaks)
labels[[best]] = bquote(underline(bold(.(labels[[best]]))))


p = ggplot(df, aes(y = parameters)) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = breaks,
                   labels = labels,
                   guide  = guide_axis(check.overlap = T))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking for a more automatic solution than this, but one way would simply be to print every other label.

```
N              = 75
df             = data.frame(parameters = paste("paramters", seq(N), sep = "_"))
df$parameters  = factor(df$parameters, levels = df$parameters, ordered = T)

best           = 9
breaks         = levels(df$parameters)
labels         = as.expression(breaks)
labels[[best]] = bquote(underline(bold(.(labels[[best]]))))

## Set all even-numbered labels to ""
labs2 <- ifelse(1:length(labels) %%2 == 0, "", labels)

p = ggplot(df, aes(y = parameters)) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = breaks,
                   labels = labs2,
                   guide  = guide_axis(check.overlap = F))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! This is a good idea, but indeed you are right, here, even-numbered labels are definitely lost. What is nice with `guide_axis(check.overlap = F)` is that if you change your window size, some labels can be visible again.

Comment: Although, I do not understand why in your solution when I change check.overlap to TRUE, then labels are completely messed up.

Comment: I think that the point is you're manually preventing the overlap by printing only every second one, so you don't need to check for it and correct it.  I'm not sure why when you change `check.overlap` to `T` it messes everything up either, unless it is identifying overlap between a blank space and the printed labels.